# Why after building my project everything is ok, but after refreshing changes disappear?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

I'm making a small web shop and i'm stuck. I want to create my main Index.html page but when i want to make 3 columns and I set their height to eg. 250px it's working but when i press f5 columns are changing their height to 20px.
In incognito theyre 250px all the time - how?
Second problem is that I can't set my height to eg. h-50 with bootstrap - it's not working even in incognito

```
<div class="container cont">
    <div class="row row-no-gutters rov">
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-50 bg-success">.col</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 kol bg-success">.col</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 kol bg-success">.col</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.cont{
    height:500px;
}
.rov{
    height:250px;
}
.kol{
    height:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the display looks ok when viewed 'incognito' but not when you just press F5 then it might be browser cache that needs clearing _ Also using Ctrl / F5 will probably work better than one key refresh

Comment: Thanks, it works but i still have problem with height in bootstrap (h-*) :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the page with Ctrl + F5. It looks like your css file has been cached by the browser. If it is not solved, Try to erase the history with the cache option.

Comment: Thanks, it works but i still have problem with height in bootstrap (h-*) :(.